# Asp.Net Core 2.1 ApiController attribute doesn't validate Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .NET Core 2.1.

This is my controller:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Cost controller
   /// </summary>
   [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
   [Produces("application/json")]
   [ApiController]
   public class CostController : ControllerBase
   {
```

And one of the routes:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Estimate cost
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info">Processing information</param>
        [HttpPost("estimate")]
        public IActionResult Estimate(ProcessingInfo info)
```

`ProcessingInfo` is defined like this:

```
public class ProcessingInfo
{
    [Range(0.0000001, double.MaxValue)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "inputSizeGB", Required = Required.Always)]
    public double InputSizeGB { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, I have the following lines:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

I also tried without the `SetCompatibilityVersion`.

Be it through integration tests using TestServer, or using Postman, if I send an invalid model:

```
{
  "inputSizeGB": -1
}
```

I get a 200-OK response, and not the expected BadRequest 400:
[image: Postman]

Note that if I manually add a check with `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` the model is declared invalid.

All this is from an existing codebase, so I'm frantically searching for what can cause such a side effect but so far I've been unlucky.

Comment: What I meant was: if I'm manually checking for ModelState (and return a 400) it is working fine. The thing is I don't want to write for every controller/route the lines `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest()` and expect ApiController to do it for me.

Comment: I made a same code as you have and validation works OK, I don't see issue which you have. Do you have other changes in Startup class?

Comment: Please post your ConfigureServices method and other relevant code from the Startup class....

Comment: Try adding `[FromBody]` attribute before controller action parameter like `public IActionResult Estimate([FromBody] ProcessingInfo info)`

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, some set up `services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);` in the  services configuration.